# errorCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "comment" at path "comments"

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When I submit the form I keep getting this:

> errorCastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "comment" at path
>   "comments"

I hope you got my question right

### This is the form req

```
action="/campground/<%= camp._id %>/comments/" method="POST">
```

### and this the route that rendering the form page

```
app.get("/campground/:id/comments/new", function(req, res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, camp){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            res.render("comments/new", {camp: camp});
        }
    });    
});
```

### This the post route that creating the comment and associating it with campground

```
app.post("/campground/:id/comments", function(req, res){
   Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, camp){
      if(err){
          console.log(err);
          res.redirect("/");
      } else {
          Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
              if(err){
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                 camp.comments.push("comment");
                 camp.save();
                 res.redirect("/campground/" + req.params.id);
              }
          });
      }
   }); 
});
```

### The app is listening to this

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are pushing a string that is `"comment"` while required either object or only id, following example may help you

```
camp.comments.push(comment);
```

or

```
camp.comments.push(comment._id);
```

rather than `camp.comments.push("comment");`